# How to change two different color of two words in string.xml using navigation drawer title in android

Tags: android, xml, string

How to change the color of `NavigationDrawer` title.I'm using two words in single item of title using strings.xml. How to change two different color of two words in `NavigationDrawer` title using android.
Example:

1.settings page

how to put this color given below

settings-`#FFFFFF`

page-`#c00000`

Comment: You can create a custom XML and can define color in your XML NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        if (navView == null)
navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.drawer_header);

Answer (score 1):

define following string in your `strings.xml`

```
<string name="str_settings"><Data><![CDATA[ <font color=#FFFFFF>settings</font> <font color=#c00000>page</font> ]]> </Data></string>
```

Then you can display this html in TextView using:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.str_settings)));
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use SpannableString and ForegroundColorSpan.

This should look something like this:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

String red = "this is red";
SpannableString redSpannable= new SpannableString(red);
redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, red.length(), 0);
builder.append(redSpannable);

String white = "this is white";
SpannableString whiteSpannable= new SpannableString(white);
whiteSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0,   white.length(), 0);
builder.append(whiteSpannable);

String blue = "this is blue";
SpannableString blueSpannable = new SpannableString(blue);
blueSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, blue.length(), 0);
builder.append(blueSpannable);

mTextView.setText(builder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

[image: Output Like this]

Comment: How to add this builder in this view....                                                                                   navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[14], navMenuIcons
    .getResourceId(14, -1)));